# httprouter, using route path with an extension

Tags: go

i'm using [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) for a simple json api server powered by golang.

i would like to have two routes with named parameters, served by two different handlers

for example, i need `/v1/1234` and `/v1/1234.json`

```
    router.GET("/v1/:id", Content)
    router.GET("/v1/:id.json", ContentJson)
```

but named parameters only match a single path segment
other ways i can solve this?

Comment: does `router.GET("/v1/:id/json", ContentJson)` work for you?

Comment: yes, it does, and is the way i'm currently using. but is ugly,  i would rather prefer the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, named parameters match an entire path segment. You could get around this by checking for the suffix in a single handler and branching from there.

```golang
router.GET("/v1/:id", Content)

func Content(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := httprouter.ParamsFromContext(r.Context())

    if strings.HasSuffix(params.ByName("id"), ".json") {
        ContentJson()
    } else {
        ContentDefault()
    }
}
```

Another way to handle different response types without multiple handlers is to make use of the [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header.

```golang
router.GET("/v1/:id", Content)

func Content(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Header.Get("Accept") == "application/json" {
        ContentJson()
    } else {
        ContentDefault()
    }
}
```

You would then set the header in the request. This is probably the cleanest solution, but not quite as straightforward for all users.

```sh
curl -H "Accept: application/json" 'http://my.api/v1/:id`
```

Comment: thanks, i'm going with checking suffix inside the same handler.
checking header is also cleaner, but not my need: the json is not intented to be consumed by machines but by browsers.